# matching dfs containing names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets that has a list of names. 1 dataset also has extra names that the other one doesnt, and another has duplicates. My goal is to create a 3rd dataframe that lists all the differences and excludes the matches

consider these dataframes:

```
df =
 Full name
dan  lastname1
dan  lastname1
bill lastname2
bob  lastname3
brad lastname4

df2=
Full name
daniel  lastname1
william lastname2
robert  lastname3
bradley lastname4
Jane    lastname5


d3 =
Full name             match       
daniel  lastname1     dan lastname1   
william lastname2     bill lastname2
robert  lastname3     bob  lastname3
bradley lastname4     brad lastname4
Jane    lastname5     NaN
```

I tried  merging the dataframes and dropping the duplicates but no luck. I think the extra names and nicknames are throwing things off.

Comment: Can you update your post with your expected df3, please?

Comment: you can get the matching values as `df1[~df1['Full name'].isin(df2['Full name'])].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) package to accomplish your task:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

THRESHOLD = 80

best_match = df2['Full name'].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df1['Full name'],
                                                                 score_cutoff=THRESHOLD))

df2['match'] = best_match.apply(pd.Series)[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
            Full name            match
0    daniel lastname1    dan lastname1
1  william lastname 2  bill lastname 2
2    robert lastname3    bob lastname3
3  bradley lastname 4  brad lastname 4
4     Jane lastname 5              NaN

>>> best_match
0      (dan lastname1, 90, 0)
1    (bill lastname 2, 85, 2)
2      (bob lastname3, 83, 3)
3    (brad lastname 4, 91, 4)
4                        None
Name: Full name, dtype: object
```

**How to install**

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy python-levenshtein
conda install -c conda-forge fuzzywuzzy python-levenshtein
```

The `python-levenshtein` package is not mandatory but it *provides a 4-10x speedup in String Matching*.