# Fuzzy-compare two dataframes of addresses and copy info from 1 to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy, difflib

I have this data set. df1 = 70,000 rows and df2 = ~30 rows.  I want to match the address to see if df2 appears in df1 and if it does than I want to show the match and also pull info from df1 to create a new df3. Sometimes the address info is off by a bit..for example (road = rd, street = st, etc )Here's an example:

```
df1 = 

address                unique key (and more columns)

123 nice road           Uniquekey1
150  spring drive       Uniquekey2
240 happy lane          Uniquekey3
80 sad parkway          Uniquekey4
etc


df2 =

address            (and more columns)

123 nice rd          
150  spring dr      
240 happy lane          
80 sad parkway         
etc
```

And this is what Id want a new dataframe :

```
df3=

address(from df2)     addressed matched(from df1)     unique key(comes from df1) (and more columns)      

123 nice rd            123 nice road                    Uniquekey1
150  spring dr         150  spring drive                Uniquekey2
240 happy lane         240 happy lane                   Uniquekey3
 80 sad parkway        80 sad parkway                   Uniquekey4
etc
```

Here's what Ive tried so far using difflib:

```
df1['key'] = df1['address']
df2['key'] = df2['address']

df2['key'] = df2['key'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['key'], n=1))

this returns what looks like a list, the answer is in []'s so then I convert the df2['key'] into a string using df2['key'] = df2['key'].apply(str)

then I try to merge using df2.merge(df1, on ='key') and no address is matching?
```

I'm not sure what it could be but any help would be greatly appreciated. I also am playing around with the fuzzywuzzy package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is similar to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68324933/15239951) of your old questions that I answered.

I slightly modified your dataframe:

```
>>> df1
             address  unique key
0      123 nice road  Uniquekey1
1  150  spring drive  Uniquekey2
2     240 happy lane  Uniquekey3
3     80 sad parkway  Uniquekey4

>>> df2  # shuffle rows
          address
0  80 sad parkway
1  240 happy lane
2  150  winter dr  # change the season :-)
3     123 nice rd
```

Use `extractOne` function from `fuzzywuzzy.process`:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

THRESHOLD = 90

best_match = \
    df2['address'].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df1['address'],
                                                      score_cutoff=THRESHOLD))
```

The output of `extractOne` is:

```
>>> best_match
0    (80 sad parkway, 100, 3)
1    (240 happy lane, 100, 2)
2                        None
3      (123 nice road, 92, 0)
Name: address, dtype: object
```

Now you can merge your 2 dataframes:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1.set_index(best_match.apply(pd.Series)[2]),
               left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

```
>>> df3
        address_x          address_y  unique key
0  80 sad parkway     80 sad parkway  Uniquekey4
1  240 happy lane                NaN         NaN
2  150  winter dr  150  spring drive  Uniquekey2
3     123 nice rd      123 nice road  Uniquekey1
```

Comment: oh boy I didnt realize that one got a response!  thanks for replying, twice! I appreciate it

Comment: The code worked however I wasnt able to match on the proper index. I think it might have to do with my dataset having multiple addresses of the same name. Is there a way that I can compensate for that?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is longer but I'll post it because maybe you can follow along better as you can see the steps as they happen.

**Set up the frames:**

```
import pandas as pd

#pip install fuzzywuzzy
#pip install python-Levenshtein
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

# matching threshold.  may need altering from 45-95 etc.  higher is better but being stricter means things aren't matched.  fiddle as required
threshold = 75

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'address': {0: '123 nice road',
  1: '150  spring drive',
  2: '240 happy lane',
  3: '80 sad parkway'},
 'unique key (and more columns)': {0: 'Uniquekey1',
  1: 'Uniquekey2',
  2: 'Uniquekey3',
  3: 'Uniquekey4'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'address': {0: '123 nice rd',
  1: '150  spring dr',
  2: '240 happy lane',
  3: '80 sad parkway'},
 'unique key (and more columns)': {0: 'Uniquekey1',
  1: 'Uniquekey2',
  2: 'Uniquekey3',
  3: 'Uniquekey4'}})
```

**Then the main code:**

```
# function used for fuzzywuzzy matching
def match_addresses(add, list_add, min_score=0):
    max_score = -1
    max_add = ''
    for x in list_add:
        score = fuzz.ratio(add, x)
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_add = x
            max_score = score
    return (max_add, max_score)

# return the fuzzywuzzy score
def scoringMatches(x, s):
    o = process.extractOne(x, s, score_cutoff = threshold)
    if o != None:
        return o[1]
    
# creating two lists from address column of both dataframes
df1_addresses = list(df1.address.unique())
df2_addresses = list(df2.address.unique())

# via fuzzywuzzy matching and using match_addresses() above
# return a dictionary of addresses where there is a match
names = []
for x in df1_addresses:
    match = match_addresses(x, df2_addresses, threshold)
    if match[1] >= threshold:
        name = (str(x), str(match[0]))
        names.append(name)
name_dict = dict(names)


# create new frame from fuzzywuzzy address matches dictionary
match_df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict.items(), columns=['df1_address', 'df2_address'])

# create new frame
df3 = pd.concat([df1, match_df], axis=1)
del df3['df1_address']

# shuffle the matched address column to be next to the original address of df1
c = df3.columns.tolist()
c.insert(1, c.pop(c.index('df2_address')))
df3 = df3.reindex(columns=c)

# add fuzzywuzzy scoring as a new column
df3['fuzzywuzzy_score'] = df3.apply(lambda x: scoringMatches(x['address'], df2['address']), axis=1)

print(df3)
```

**Output:**

```
    address             df2_address     unique key (and more columns)   fuzzywuzzy_score
0   123 nice road       123 nice rd     Uniquekey1                      92
1   150 spring drive    150 spring dr   Uniquekey2                      90
2   240 happy lane      240 happy lane  Uniquekey3                      100
3   80 sad parkway      80 sad parkway  Uniquekey4                      100
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I really appreciate it!  I followed along and everything worked up until I got to the c=df3.column.tolist() section. The code worked however I wasnt able to match on the proper index.  I think it might have to do with my dataset having multiple addresses of the same name. Is there a way that I can compensate for that?