# Join/merge/concat 2 dataframes in pandas where the key columns are inconsistently spelled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, fuzzywuzzy

I have two dataframes where there is only one key column, and it is people's full names. There are inconsistencies between the two columns and their spellings. For example, one name may have a letter missing, a name prefix like Mr. (where the other df does not), extra spaces, etc. I have double-checked that in both dataframes these columns are both object types/strings. I want to merge these two dataframes.

The code

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df1["BestMatch"] = df1["FULL_NAME"].map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x,df2["FULL_NAME"])[0])
```

gives me the error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have also tried

```
#import difflib 

#difflib.get_close_matches
```

```
df1['FULL_NAME'] = df1['FULL_NAME'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x,df2['FULL_NAME'])[0])
```

gives me the error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've searched for how to fix these errors/the code, and nothing seems to quite give me the right answer. I am relatively inexperienced, and I'm guessing there is something I'm missing, but I'm not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have NaN in the column `FULL_NAME` of `df1`.

Reproducible error:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'FULL_NAME': ['Louis', np.nan, 'Alexandre']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'FULL_NAME': ['Mr Louis', 'Mr Paul', 'Mr Alexandre']})
```

```
>>> df1["FULL_NAME"].map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2["FULL_NAME"])[0])
...
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How to avoid this situation: `dropna` before `apply/map`.

```
df1['BestMatch'] = df1["FULL_NAME"].dropna().map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x,df2["FULL_NAME"])[0])
```

```
>>> df1
   FULL_NAME     BestMatch
0      Louis      Mr Louis
1        NaN           NaN
2  Alexandre  Mr Alexandre
```

I wrote a similar answer on how to merge to dataframe using `fuzzywuzzy`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945895/15239951

**Debug**
Try to debug manually:

```
for x in df1['FULL_NAME']:
    try:
        b = process.extractOne(x, df2["FULL_NAME"])[0]
        print(f"{x} <-> {b}")
    except TypeError:
        print(f"XXX Problem with '{x}'")
```

Output:

```
Louis <-> Mr Louis
XXX Problem with 'nan'
Alexandre <-> Mr Alexandre
```

**Merge** Use index `[2]` instead of best match name `[0]`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'FULL_NAME': ['Louis', np.nan, 'Alexandre'], 
                    'DATA1': [10, 20, 30]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'FULL_NAME': ['Mr Louis', 'Mr Paul', 'Mr Alexandre'],
                    'DATA2': [11, 21, 31]})

best_match_index = lambda x: process.extractOne(x,df2["FULL_NAME"])[2]
df1['BestMatch'] = df1["FULL_NAME"].dropna().map(best_match_index)

out = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='BestMatch', how='left')
```

Output

```
>>> out
      FULL_NAME_x  DATA2 FULL_NAME_y  DATA1  BestMatch
0.0      Mr Louis     11       Louis   10.0          0
NaN       Mr Paul     21         NaN    NaN          1
2.0  Mr Alexandre     31   Alexandre   30.0          2
```

Comment: For both dataframes, there are no null objects in the key column.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try to debug please?

Comment: Your code `df1['BestMatch'] = df1["FULL_NAME"].dropna().map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x,df2["FULL_NAME"])[0])` does not give me an error (this is definitely an improvement), although it doesn't get me to the join/merge step. I tried to join using `df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1.set_index(best_match.apply(pd.Series)[2]),
               left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')` ...and it doesn't seem to actually join with the best match. (It joins with the names (and data) at the top of df1 and the names and data at the top of df2) @Corralien

Comment: I updated my answer to merge the dataframes.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to make this work! I had been trying to make this work for quite awhile! @Corralien